# How to add new column on initialization for a class that inherits from a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object, init

I am creating a class that inherits from a Pandas DataFrame. After initialization, I would like to run a few methods, which will add columns to the dataframe that are calculated based on the data in the other columns of the dataframe.

A good example would be if I created a class called “NewClass” that automatically adds a column named “multiplied” that is 2x the column named “value”. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need something like this with [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) ?

```
class NewClass(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self["multiplied"] = self["value"].mul(2)
        #self.insert(0, "multiplied", self["value"].mul(2)) #to choose the position

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return NewClass
```

Output/Test :

```
df = NewClass({"value": [10, 20]})
​
print(df)

   value  multiplied
0     10          20
1     20          40
```

Comment: Added @property to return a NewClass instance when you slice the original one else it will return a DataFrame instance. However subclassing a DataFrame is never a good idea IMHO :-)

Comment: Sounds fair, thank you Corralien ;) And regarding your second point, I think so too.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#override-constructor-properties

Comment: Hey so just wanted to add, I did end up solving the problem, through a metaclass and a method that is run by that meta class (in case it wasn't obvious, I simplified the problem for this post). Was it unnecessarily complicated? Probably. Did it do anything that couldn't have been done better a different way? Probably not. Was it annoying as s**t? Yes! Did it work? ...Yes? At least, it hasn't broken so far. And to be clear, yeah, it's generally a dumb idea to subclass a DataFrame. The only reason I wanted to do it was for reusability of various methods.